# Why does this while loop keep looping even when its false? In C++

Tags: c++

This is the code in question:

```
int integer;
while (integer != 0 || integer != 1) {
            cout << "Choose an integer: \n0\n1\n";
            cin >> integer;
            }
```

When I type 1 it continues looping even though the statement is false.
I have had this problem before or similar but it got fixed in a weird way that seems to not be working right now.
The other code that was having problems was this one:

```
while(chosen != 1 || chosen != 2 || chosen != 3)
    {
      cin >> chosen;
    }
```

I got it fixed by doing this:

```
while(chosen < 1 || chosen > 3)
```

Does annyone know whats happening here? Ty in advance!

Comment: Well, which `integer` values are you expecting to pass this condition: `integer != 0 || integer != 1`?

Comment: What I want is for the loop to stop (condition is false) when someone types 0 or 1

Comment: What πάνταῥεῖ is trying to tell you is: `integer != 0` and `integer != 1` can't be both `false` at the same time. `integer != 0 → false` can only be satisfied for `integer == 0`. But for `integer == 0` it follows that `integer != 1 → true`. And it also works vice versa. In other words the loop condition will never be false. – Did you perchance mean to use **logical and** instead of **or**?

Comment: Oooh Tysm sorry for the dumb mistake i forgot that the OR means that the condition is true if one of each is true ty again

Comment: There are no integral values for which the condition `integer != 0 || integer != 1` is false.    Possibility 1 : `integer` is `0`.   In that case  `integer != 0` is `false` but `integer != 1` is `true`, so your condition is `true`.    Possibility 2:  `integer` is non-zero.  In that case, `integer != 0` is always true, so your loop condition is `true`.    There is no third possibility, since there is no possible value of `integer` that is simultaneously equal to zero while being non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me put you out of your misery

```
while(chosen != 1 && chosen != 2 && chosen != 3)
    {
      cin >> chosen;
    }
```

This is a common issue, people translate the human idea in their heads into code: "if its not 1 or 2 or 3 then do xx". But that doesnt work.

```
 (chosen != 1 || chosen != 2 || chosen != 3)
```

will always be true.
If chosen is say 0 then `chosen != 1` is true. So the overall condition is true.

If chosen is 1 (which should be the end of your loop) then `chosen !=1` is false, BUT `chosen != 2` is true so the overall condition is still true (its true if one of the clauses is true, this is what 'or' / '||' means).

In fact there is no value for chosen which will cause the overall condition to be false. Chosen is always going to not equal one of 1 or 2 or 3.

Your problem came from the looseness of human thought, in conversation we would get what you mean, but not computers. What you wanted was "if its not 1 and its not 2 and its not 3 do xx". Ie

```
while(chosen != 1 && chosen != 2 && chosen != 3)
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo everybody else was just saying 'its obvious dude' and not helping at all, i am sure OP will work out why it works.

Comment: Ty yall, this was answer was more of a "this is what you have to write" I figured it out thanks to user datenwolf on the comments of the comment

Comment: That's all not useful for future researchers coming over here regarding similar problems. It should be removed from this site altogether.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ edited

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am sure future researchers will be much happier now